# How can I use InfoPath 2013 with SharePoint 2013 to upload a document when the user submits the form?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, infopath

Background: I want to make a form in SharePoint for the user to submit vendor information. They fill out the form and attach a document with products and pricing. I can't figure out how to make a form that I can publish to SharePoint to do this. When I use InfoPath's file attachment it fails to publish. I tried using info from this link [here](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2010/01/upload-document-sharepoint-infopath-form/) but I'm not sure that it's actually a SharePoint form instead of a standard form.

My solution doesn't need to use the attachment I just want users to be able to easily submit the form with the attachment at the same time.

P.s. Sorry if my question is bad. First time using SharePoint, InfoPath, and posting here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Any list that supports attachments should allow you to add an InfoPath form control for that field which will allow the users to add the attachment as part of the form submittal.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply was a little busy with another project i was given. The issue I have with this is that I'm trying to have the InfoPath form be accessed through the web browser.(So users don't need InfoPath on their computers) When I try to publish the form with the attachment it tells me that SharePoint does not support attachments. So at this point I'm thinking I'd have to have the form use a button control to select the document and send it to a library, but I have no idea how to do this. Any suggestions as to this or something else I could try?

Comment: If you create a custom list in SharePoint and then use the Customize Form function from the List ribbon you should automatically get a form that has only Title and Attachment fields.  The InfoPath overlays for standard SharePoint lists are far more flexible than forms submitted to form libraries and will allow you the functionality you need with the forms being filled out completely in the browser.

Comment: If you aren't certain of what I mean there is a nice video on it here:   http://sharepoint-videos.com/module-1/sp10-create-a-sharepoint-list-form-using-infopath/